# Demo App Jetcaster : Unable to upgrade Android Gradle plugin using 7.0.0-alpha09 to 7.0.0-alpha10

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

While building the latest version of Jetcaster demo app on the lastest version of Android Studio Canary 10.

Got the following
This project is using version 7.0.0-alpha09 of the Android Gradle plugin, which is incompatible with this version of Android Studio.
To continue importing this project (Jetcaster), Android Studio will upgrade the project's build files to use version 7.0.0-alpha10 of Android Gradle plugin (you can learn more about this version of the plugin from the release notes).

Android studio popup windows to start upgrading, but fails

Comment: Hi ROM, It would be great if you could provide  screenshot of error log, gradle and manifest file for better understanding of above issue. Also mention any steps that you had taken to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do it manually.

In `dependencies.kt` at path `src/main/java/com/example/compose/jetchat/buildsrc/dependencies.kt` change `const val androidGradlePlugin = "com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.0-alpha09"` to `const val androidGradlePlugin = "com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.0-alpha10"`

Stolen from https://github.com/android/compose-samples/issues/274